# CodeIgniter URL segment not read as a property

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a project where the client needs a property to be added to the URL address (which is dynamically generated) but it should be invisible to CI. I don't want it to be added as a parameter in the methods and eventually worked with. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: do you mean with invisible that a controller isn't affected by the property ?

Comment: Edit question with example url of what you have now and what you want to have and also all relevant code used. Read [how to ask](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am trying to do. I don't want any controller methods to be affected by it. It should be as there is no value. 

Current url: https://test.beta.com/member/work
New url : https://test.beta.com/member/work/12451234123

and the 12451234123 is the thing that is not supposed to be affecting anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe add $_GET parameters to your url. `http://mywebiste.com/controller/method?paramter1=32234&parameter2=35734`.

Then retrieve them with `$this->input->get();`.